# Create grails war without version number

Tags: grails

How do I create a grails war file so that it doesn't have the version number

(e.g. foo-0.1.war)

attached to the end when I execute the 'grails war' command?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think you can specify the war name in the war command.

```
grails war foo.war
```

Also check the latest Grails documentation for where to set this as a configuration option. See the other answers for details.

Comment: Sidenote: when doing so, by default the WAR file will not be compiled to the `target` directory as one might expect, but to your project directory. However you can specify the path too, see http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Command%20Line/war.html

Answer (score 43):

In case anybody comes upon this article and is using Grails 1.3.x, the configuration option has changed from `grails.war.destFile` in `Config.groovy` to being `grails.project.war.file` in `BuildConfig.groovy`.

Also the file name is relative to the project workspace, so it should have a value like:

`grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}.war"`

This is according to the latest [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/17.%20Deployment.html).

Comment: this is also relevant for grails 2.x

Answer (score 10):

From the [Grails Documentation](http://grails.org/doc/1.0.x/), ***Chapter 17, Deployment***

> There are also many ways in which you can customise the WAR file that is
>   created. For example, you can specify
>   a path (either absolute or relative)
>   to the command that instructs it where
>   to place the file and what name to
>   give it:
>
> ```
> grails war /opt/java/tomcat-5.5.24/foobar.war
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can add a line to
>   Config.groovy that changes the default
>   location and filename:
>
> ```
> grails.war.destFile = "foobar-prod.war"
> ```
>
> Of course, any command line argument
>   that you provide overrides this
>   setting.

Comment: This is actually the better answer

Answer (score 5):

Rolling up the other excellent answers.  There are several options:

Explicitly set it on the command line:  `grails war foo.war`

Set the `app.version` property to empty in application.properties will cause the war to be named `foo.war`.

Explicitly set the name of the war using the `grails.war.destFile` property in Config.groovy

Answer (score 4):

Grails 3.x has switched to gradle and uses the [war](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html) plugin.  You can just specify name like this in the `build.gradle` file:

```
war {
    archiveName 'foo.war'
}
```

Comment: For Grails 3 you have to use 'archiveName' instead of 'archive'.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621966/create-grails-3-war-without-version-number

Answer (score 1):

Another way to generate war files without version number is to keep the property, **app.version**, empty in the **application.properties**

Comment: This works and is the best answer, because it's the primary source for that information.

Answer (score 0):

I am kind of late to the party... but anyway:

I think the reason behind removing the version number is to eliminate the need to rename the war file so it deploys on "*correct*" context path **/appName**. If that's the case then a better option is to use a versioned war filename so you can deploy multiple versions at the same time on tomcat using the following naming pattern in **grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy**:

```
grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}##${appVersion}.war"
```

As explained in http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Parallel_deployment

This method applies to wars in general, not only grails' wars.

Comment: The grails.project.war.file property didn't sem to work for grails 4

Comment: Hi @user2782001, Do you find the way now that how to create .war with context path name? for grails 4

Comment: I don't use grails anymore but maybe it works like grails 3.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39277804/1284183