# Create Grails 3 WAR without version number

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

In Grails 2 we could define WAR filename like this:

```
grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}.war"
```

How can I override the war filename in Grails 3?

Thanks Jeff.

I have added line like thisin build.gradle:

```
war {
    archiveName "${war.baseName}.war"
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `build.gradle` you can do something like `war.archiveName='jeff.war'`.  See https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War%3aarchiveName.

Comment: The value of course can be dynamic: `war.archiveName="${war.baseName}.war"` too.

Comment: It's worth noting that the setting of this property has to be done **AFTER** the war plugin is applied

Comment: Correct.  You can't access anything provided by a plugin until the plugin has been applied.

Comment: Can't get this to work in grails 4. The gradle docs also say archiveName is being deprecated so I tried archiveFileName as well. Still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A more detailed answer: Add this to wrapper task in build.gradle so it creates different war file name based on each environment.

```
war.archiveName="${war.baseName}_${grails.util.Environment.current.name}.war"
```

Then create war file like this.

```
grails -Dgrails.env=staging war
```

Comment: "Add this to wrapper task in build.gradle..." - What does the wrapper task have to do with this?